# How to update settings on dask workers' container which were initially loaded through a register worker callback?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed

So I have 2 containers with dask workers setup. I'll refer to them as

- `main` which has 4 workers and the full application
- `remote` which has another 4 workers, the full app's code but isn't running the full app, just the workers code.

I'm passing a dictionary with settings to each worker from the `main` container through a setup function callback using [register_worker_callbacks()](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Client.register_worker_callbacks)

I do it like so:

```
await client.register_worker_callbacks(lambda: setup_worker(log_config, settings))
```

And the setup function

```
def setup_worker(log_config, settings_object):
    setup_logging(log_config)
    settings.__dict__.update(settings_object.__dict__)
```

Both containers have this piece of code so it works fine, no problems.

BUT I also have a cronjob running daily which retrieves a new settings file (in JSON) from an external source and from, `settings` object on the `main` container is reloaded / updated.

This newly updated `settings` object needs to propagate and update the settings on the workers too, basically I need a way to call the last line of the `setup_worker` function again, doing the exact same thing. But since the workers are already registered and connected at this point, I can't re-use the same callback, can I? How would I achieve the same?

Comment: What are you looking to reconfigure so often that you want a more programmatic solution?

Comment: @joebeeson I have specific settings being computed daily which are then used by the workers for their own computations. In any case, is there a simple solution for that? Or do I just need to scatter or something?

Comment: Settings unique to _your_ usages or settings which modify Dask's functionality?

Comment: Unique to my usages, unrelated to dask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked simply by using

```
await client.run(func, args)
```

as documented [here](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Client.run)

It takes a callable / function and executes it on all workers without using the scheduler by default. So to update the same settings which are usually loaded by a callback, you can just call that same function with the same arguments here.

So I ended up with 2 functions like so:

```
def setup_worker(log_config, settings_object):
    setup_logging(log_config)
    update_settings(settings_object)

def update_settings(settings_object):
    settings.__dict__.update(settings_object.__dict__)
```

The setup callback is set up the same way as before

```
await client.register_worker_callbacks(lambda: setup_worker(log_config, settings))
```

But I have an additional function being called when the settings are updated on the `main` container like so:

```
def update_settings():
    ...
    await client.run(update_settings, settings)
```